# ggplot2 plots polygons with wrong topologies

Tags: shapefile, polygon, r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot polygons in R using `ggplot2`. In GRASS, QGIS and normal R the map renders fine, but `ggplot2` seems to have some kind of topological difficultes I can't explain. With normal R it looks like this:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
regions <- readOGR(dir, layer)
plot(regions)
```

[image: Plot with R]

And with `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=regions, aes(long, lat))
```

[image: Plot with ggplot2]

To add to the confusion, `gplot2` is connecting polygons that have absolutely nothing to do with each other - Iceland to Ireland, for instance. How can I fix the plot?

Answer (score 4):

A group aesthetic is missing:

```
ggplot() + geom_polygon(data=fortify(regions), aes(long, lat, group=group))
```

Otherwise the last point of a polygon is connected with the first point of the next polygon.

See also here:

- [SpatialPolygonDataFrame plotting using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174703/)
- [Remove connecting lines in ggplot2 geom_polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169873)